# How to make circle based on percentage?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I can create a circle, but instead I need it to start at "12:00" and go to a certain percentage.

```
 let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100,y: 100), radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

    cell.progress.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Comment: Change the start and end angle to meet your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to adjust the start and end angles to meet your criteria.

"12:00" on the circle would be 3pi/2 or -pi/2 (`- CGFloat.pi / 2`). A full circle is 2pi (`2 * CGFloat.pi`). A percentage of that is of course `CGFloat.pi * 2 * percentage`. So the end would be your start + that percentage.

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(
   arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100),
   radius: 20,
   startAngle: - .pi / 2,
   endAngle: - .pi / 2 + .pi * 2 * percentage ,
   clockwise: true
)
```

where `percentage` is some `CGFloat` in the range `0.0` to `1.0`.